# PHP form doesn't work only on specific computers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, forms

Have a bizarre problem where a PHP form doesn't work, but only on two specific computers. It works everywhere else without problem. Would appreciate any ideas of where to look to resolve this.

- form is PHP based
- has validators to check required fields are completed; if there are errors it alerts the user to needed corrections and doesn't allow submission until this happens.
- on form submit, the form contents are emailed to a set address
- form contents are also recorded to MySQL
- form redirects to a "thanks" page once recorded.
- form DOES utilize jquery as well.

For 99% of users, the form works perfectly, send the email copy and records data to database. However, I have two users (at different IPs and different regions) where the form is not working properly I can't figure out.

Here is what happens in this scenario:

- form is completed properly and submitted
- form contents are NOT emailed to the set address
- form contents are NOT recorded to MySQL
- form DOES redirect to "thanks" page however.

I do not see any server errors, but I can see these two users have been directed to the "thanks" page as normally would happen.

- there is nothing in the form contents from these users that would otherwise prevent submission (have tested same contents from other computers/devices and it submits fine)
- can't seem to find anything else suggesting why it would fail for these other users.

I've tested using various browsers, devices, from different IPs. Have asked these users to try using various browsers, incognito sessions. Also looked into settings to make sure scripts weren't blocked, and disabled browser extensions.

I believe at this point perhaps it's device specific but don't know where to look past this point.

In any case it's bizarre. Appreciate any and all input. Thanks!

Comment: How can we possibly help without seeing the code that deals with this emailing process. We are not clarevoyant

Comment: Code is proprietary to my employer.  The problem is not that it "doesn't work".  It works on 99% of devices.  It is not working on two specific computers at different IPs.  I'm looking for input/ideas on where I can look to narrow down this problem.

Comment: What regions are these users that fail to mail in?

Comment: Is it an encoding issue?

Comment: I can keep guessing all day if you think it will help!

Comment: Both U.S., one is in Minnesota and the other in Washington state.  So completely different areas.  Each user also used a different browser.  The only thing I can figure is perhaps there's something with browser extension or machine-specific but beyond that I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly I appreciate the ideas.

Comment: are the user behind a firewall/proxy? do they use the right URL? (wouldn't be the first user that try to insert real data in a test system)

Comment: Sounds like a validation code issue. Something is failing validation but is not being properly reported

Comment: How is validation done? May be javascript and Javascript is disabled by the user in trouble?